# Can I go as a Skilled Migrant to NZ without bachelors?

Tags: visa, immigration, indian-citizens, new-zealand, new-zealand-citizens

I am 26, unmarried with 5 years of experience. But I don't have a bachelors. My education qualification is high school. When I went over New Zealand immigration website, 'bachelors' looks like the minimum requirement.

Is it possible to migrate to New Zealand from India for a job in software industry?
If I don't have an education qualification, is it possible? If it's possible, how does the process looks?

Comment: Did you check https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/tools/points-indicator-smc-28aug and https://www.immigration.govt.nz/formshelp/skilled-migrant/your-recognised-work-experience?

Answer (score 1):

On a purely formal level, not having a Bachelor's degree does not exclude you from the Skilled Migrant visa. The [minimal requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skilled_Migrant_Category_(New_Zealand)) are being aged 55 or under, healthy, of good character, and speaking English.

Realistically however, it's going to be extremely difficult if not impossible. The system is designed to favor people with higher qualifications. You would need a job offer from a New Zealand employer outside Auckland with above-average pay to even get the minimum number of points.

That's if your professional experience is recognized, which probably would not be the case if I understand the system correctly. Having a job in the “Long Term Skill Shortage List” helps (as otherwise work in India would not even count) but it can only be considered as such if you met [the minimal qualifications](https://skillshortages.immigration.govt.nz/assets/uploads/long-term-skill-shortage-list.pdf) before starting this work. That, rather than not having a bachelor *per se*, is what would doom your application.